# Interpolate between columns via spline

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(dates = c("2020-12-31", "2021-01-31"),
                 x1 = c(0.50, 0.60),
                 x3 = c(1.00, 0.90),
                 x5 = c(1.50, 1.80),
                 x7 = c(2.00, 2.10),
                 x12 = c(2.50, 2.60),
                 x15 = c(3.00, 3.10))
```

I would like to interpolate using a spline between each column (and add a column inbetween to store the interpolation). Because every row is a date, every row should only interpolate across columns, row by row. I would expect the output to look something like:

```
df_inter <- data.frame(dates = c("2020-12-31", "2021-01-31"),
                       x1 = c(0.50, 0.60),
                       x2 = c(0.75, 0.65),
                       x3 = c(1.00, 0.90),
                       x4 = c(1.25, 1.35),
                       x5 = c(1.50, 1.80),
                       x6 = c(1.75, 1.95),
                       x7 = c(2.00, 2.10),
                       x8 = c(2.10, 2.20),
                       x9 = c(2.20, 2.30),
                       x10 = c(2.30, 2.40),
                       x11 = c(2.40, 2.50), 
                       x12 = c(2.50, 2.60),
                       x13 = c(2.70, 2.80),
                       x14 = c(2.70, 2.90),
                       x15 = c(3.00, 3.10))
```

The real dataframe has several hundred rows.

Comment: You cannot perform spline interpolation without an `x` component. You only have a `y` component (columns).

Comment: And a linear approx approach?

Comment: Its going to be the same. You cannot do any interpolation without an `x` component. It is easy to see, suppose I have the points y1, y3, and I want to find y2. I clearly, without knowing where on the x-axis you are (x1, x2, x3), cannot guess y2. If x2 is any value not equal to (x1 + x3)/2, the mean of y1, y3 would be wrong. To do interpolation you need a line (xi, yi) (i.e., coordinates), not points (just y_i).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to use column names `x1`, `x2`, ..., `x15` as the `x` values and entries in `df` as the `y` values. Probably you can try this

```
x <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", names(df[-1])))
y <- t(df[-1])

cbind(
    df[1],
    data.frame(t(sapply(
        1:ncol(y),
        \(k) splinefun(x, y[, k])(seq(max(x)))
    )))
)
```

which gives

```
       dates  X1        X2  X3       X4  X5       X6  X7       X8       X9
1 2020-12-31 0.5 0.7520844 1.0 1.245831 1.5 1.764590 2.0 2.168296 2.279916
2 2021-01-31 0.6 0.5878255 0.9 1.374349 1.8 2.014778 2.1 2.174178 2.261128
       X10      X11 X12      X13      X14 X15
1 2.357387 2.423239 2.5 2.609420 2.770134 3.0
2 2.360988 2.473899 2.6 2.740956 2.904527 3.1
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! Indeed using the column names was a handy solution.